# Linkedin Link share does not work properly

Tags: share, linkedin-api

Hy there,

Since several weeks I have a Link that does not show the right og-data in the link preview.
https://adora.vzug.com/

Somehow the preview window shows data that is outdated since about a month. Is there a way to refetch the data?

Thanks!

Comment: You can try adding a bogus querystring to the URL to check if that refreshes the cache when sharing: https://adora.vzug.com/?cache=20170929

Comment: Thank you. I tried that already. But tht seems to be a pretty strange bug. Also this link displays a title (startting with "[:de]"), which is nowehre in the source code.. Seems to be a bug..

Comment: Yes, I only found trouble with sharing links on LinkedIn. Your link and its og tags look good in the Facebook Sharing Debugger so I'm pretty sure it's LinkedIn related. I found in the past that removing the og:image sometimes results in a good description and the other way around, but using them together is buggy to say the least. Sorry I can't be of any more help.